# openCV and Threads issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

I'm trying to fit facedetect from openCV on my QT code, all run fine until i decided to create a thread for my openCV code so I can run another things while the face detect is on.

the problem is if i call class->start(); my program breaks in the while loop in the run() but if i call the class.run(); (like a normal function) it runs as usual! what can be wrong?

code:

```
faceTracker::faceTracker()
{ 

qDebug("teste1");
filename = "/Users/marcomartins/Documents/QT/DisplUM/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml";

/* load the classifier
    note that I put the file in the same directory with this code */
cascade = ( CvHaarClassifierCascade* )cvLoad( filename, 0, 0, 0 );

/* setup memory buffer; needed by the face detector */
storage = cvCreateMemStorage( 0 );

/* initialize camera */
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 );

/* always check */
assert( cascade && storage && capture );

/* create a window */
cvNamedWindow( "video DisplUM", 1 );


}

void faceTracker::detectFaces( IplImage *img )
{

/* detect faces */
        faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(
        img,
        cascade,
        storage,
        1.1,
        3,
        0 /*CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNNING*/,
        cvSize( 40, 40 ) );

/* for each face found, draw a red box */
for( i = 0 ; i < ( faces ? faces->total : 0 ) ; i++ ) {
    CvRect *r = ( CvRect* )cvGetSeqElem( faces, i );
    cvRectangle( img,
                 cvPoint( r->x, r->y ),
                 cvPoint( r->x + r->width, r->y + r->height ),
                 CV_RGB( 255, 0, 0 ), 1, 8, 0 );
    qDebug("caras: %d", faces->total);
}

/* display video */
cvShowImage( "video", img );
}


void faceTracker::run( )
{
qDebug("teste2");

while( key != 'q' ) {
    /* get a frame */
    frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
qDebug("teste3");
    /* always check */
    if( !frame ) break;

    /* 'fix' frame */
    cvFlip( frame, frame, 1 );
    frame->origin = 0;

    /* detect faces and display video */
    detectFaces( frame );

    /* quit if user press 'q' */
    key = cvWaitKey( 10 );

}

/* free memory */
cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvDestroyWindow( "video" );
cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade( &cascade );
cvReleaseMemStorage( &storage );
}
```

main code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  faceTracker * ft = new faceTracker();
  ft->start();
}
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: Where and what is class->start()? If you want more help you'll need to share more code. We can't tell what's wrong without any more information.

Comment: What do you mean by "my program breaks in the while loop"?

Comment: code edited to include the main. about the while loop I mean that the qDebug("teste3"); don't show so the problem is in         frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
this is what i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
I can't create windows outside the main thread, that is why it was crashing. If i comment the window creation all works good (face detection included)

Answer (score 0):

The loop will only break if `cvQueryFrame()` returns a *NULL* frame or if the user presses `q` on the keyboard.

Add a debug so you know when the first situation happens:

```
frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
if( !frame ) 
{  
  qDebug("cvQueryFrame failed!");
  break;
}
```

Are you sure `cvCaptureFromCAM(0)` works ? Depending on the OS I have to pass `-1` for it. But the fact is that you'll never know if `cvCaptureFromCAM(0)`succeeded because you don't check the return, and this might be the problem!

```
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
if (!capture)
{
  qDebug("cvCaptureFromCAM failed!");
  //exit(0); or whatever
}
```

**EDIT:**

Pay huge attention to this: you are creating a window named "video DisplUM" but you are trying to display the frames on a different window, named "video".

Anyway, it's also better if you change the window creation function to use the appropriate enum:

```
cvNamedWindow("video DisplUM", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
```

and on `faceTracker::run( )` comment `detectFaces()` for now and add a call to cvShowImage( "video DisplUM", frame );

Always be sure your application works with the minimum requirements before adding fancy stuffs, like face detection. My final suggestion is: write enough code just to capture the images from one thread and display them on a window, and then go from there.

Comment: i've just added it and no message on the debug =/ i've found someone with same issue but no answer too: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.opencv.devel/278

Comment: Have you managed to run a simple application using OpenCV? Could you see the captured frames on a window? Have you seen it work?

Comment: For testing purposes I would execute `cvCaptureFromCAM()` from the same thread that is doing `cvQueryFrame()`.

Comment: yes it runs flawless if I don't use thread. and If i put all the calls I do in the facetracker() constructor in the run happens the same =/

Comment: Move the initialization of the camera to the beginning of `faceTracker::run( )`, before the loop starts. I have already succeeded grabbing frames from another thread in the past. Unfortunately I don't have that code right now. Which OpenCV version are you using?

Comment: Make sure you also remove **capture** from `assert()`. I trust that you already knew that.

Comment: nothing changes beside the fact that the qDebug("teste 2.5") inside the loop before frame = cvQueryFrame( capture ); now isn't called

Comment: Which OpenCV version and which OS are you using?

Comment: opencv 2.0 osx snow leopard 10.6

Comment: OpenCV is already on version 2.2. You should at least be using v2.1, which I know it works on Mac.

Comment: 2.0 works too, i've downloaded from their site a dmg... that is not the problem, as i've said before in single thread works great

Comment: Then you have a problem on your code. I updated the answer, you should have another look.

Comment: i've noticed that bug already and fixed, it created 2 windows instead of one. commenting the detect faces don't solve nothing =/

Comment: You have to fix that in the code you pasted here too so others don't get mislead.

Comment: I think that qt threads are somehow limited in memory. if I put on a while(1) loop an i++ and print it, if i use threads it stops at +- 17000 and if don't use threads it goes unlimited!

Comment: it was missing the ft->wait(); in the main thread!! that was the problem, the thread was terminating because main was terminating

Comment: ah my mistake, after all that wait was mising but I still have a crash =/

Comment: using qDebugs my problem is in the detectFaces function in the faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(...) (qDebug again)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue.  What I found is that I had to rebuild OpenCV and include the TBB libraries.  This adds threading support to OpenCV.  Once I did this, I was able to pop up windows in any thread I chose.  I've tested this on versions 2.1 and 2.2, using both C and C++ implementations.